# Detect missing (non existing) rows within a dataframe and replace them with NA

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have got a dataframe of ~12000 observations with two columns "Code" and "Date". Each code should have 4 observations and therefore 4 dates, but I have got missing values (not NA, but non-existing rows) within the "Date" column.

Here an example of my dataframe:

```
Station Date        
7002    17/12/1966  
7002    05/05/1968  
7002    30/10/1968  
7002    16/08/1970      
7003    02/12/1966  
7003    05/05/1968  
7003    31/10/1968  
8004    04/07/1968  
8004    15/11/1968  
8006    13/10/1966  
8006    23/09/1967  
8006    01/09/1968
```

[....]

**What I need to do is detect for each code the rows which are missing.**

I am using "water years", which start from the 1st October and end on the next 30th September e.g. 01/10/1998 - 30/09/1999. *This is the difficult thing, which makes my question different from the other ones similar.*

The time period considered ranges from 01/10/1966 to 30/09/1970 (4 water years) and the observations in the column "Date" are already fixed for water years (i.e. one observation per water year).

My output should be like:
e.g.

```
Station Date       
7002    17/12/1966  
7002    05/05/1968
7002    30/10/1968
7002    16/08/1970    
7003    02/12/1966
7003    05/05/1968  
7003    31/10/1968  
7003    NA
8004    NA
8004    04/07/1968  
8004    15/11/1968  
8004    NA
8006    13/10/1966  
8006    23/09/1967  
8006    01/09/1968  
8006    NA
[...]
```

Comment: You state you had "12000 observations with three columns "Code" and "Date" - there are only two columns here.

Comment: sorry, just fixed.

Comment: It looks like for station 8006 you have two observations in the same water year.

Comment: eipi10 went the distance and provided a fantastic solution. My only comment would be to get a quick idea of which stations are missing data, you could run `table(unlist(dat$ID))[table(unlist(dat$ID)) < 4]` - which will let you know which Stations have less than 4 entries, then just `rbind()` NA rows for those particular stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
```

**Set up sample data:**

```
dat = read.table(text="Station Date        Day
7002    17/12/1966  77
                 7002    05/05/1968  582
                 7002    30/10/1968  760
                 7002    16/08/1970  1415    
                 7003    02/12/1966  62
                 7003    05/05/1968  582
                 7003    31/10/1968  761
                 8004    04/07/1968  4294
                 8004    15/11/1968  4428
                 8006    13/10/1966  5856
                 8006    23/09/1967  6567
                 8006    01/09/1968  6910", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat$Date = as.Date(dat$Date, format=c("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**Add water year:** I've assumed that the water year is named by the year of the start of the water year. For example, water year 01/10/1967 - 30/09/1968 is water year 1967.

```
dat$water.year = ifelse(month(dat$Date) %in% 1:9, year(dat$Date) - 1, year(dat$Date))
```

**Add rows for missing years:** I do this by merging with a new data frame that includes all combinations of `Station` and `water.year`.

```
full_join(expand.grid(Station=unique(dat$Station), water.year=1966:1969),
          dat,
          by=c("Station","water.year")) %>% arrange(Station, water.year)
```

> ```
>    Station water.year       Date  Day
> 1     7002       1966 1966-12-17   77
> 2     7002       1967 1968-05-05  582
> 3     7002       1968 1968-10-30  760
> 4     7002       1969 1970-08-16 1415
> 5     7003       1966 1966-12-02   62
> 6     7003       1967 1968-05-05  582
> 7     7003       1968 1968-10-31  761
> 8     7003       1969       <NA>   NA
> 9     8004       1966       <NA>   NA
> 10    8004       1967 1968-07-04 4294
> 11    8004       1968 1968-11-15 4428
> 12    8004       1969       <NA>   NA
> 13    8006       1966 1966-10-13 5856
> 14    8006       1966 1967-09-23 6567
> 15    8006       1967 1968-09-01 6910
> 16    8006       1968       <NA>   NA
> 17    8006       1969       <NA>   NA
> ```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot! but the "water.year" column is shifted forward by one year. e.g. 7002 1966-12-17 is water year 1966 (not 1967), etc... how can I fix the problem? I tried to remove +1 but the dataframe will mess. Thanks

Comment: See updated code. Two changes: One, fix the water.year calculation. Two, change 1967:1970 to 1966:1969 in `expand.grid`.